# changing the display properties of grub

Tags: grub2, display

I would like to remove the rectangular box and the instructions displayed along with the (entries) in grub that appear during the boot.I searched for the grub design file but i couldn't find one apart from /etc/default/grub.can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

[Grub2 community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) has descriptions about changing menu items, backgrounds, etc.
At the end of the page are links for

Grub2/CustomMenus

Grub2/Displays

Grub2/Installing

Grub2/ISOBoot

Grub2/Setup

Grub2/Passwords

Grub2/Submenus

Grub2/Troubleshooting

Grub2/Upgrading

Grub 2 (Ubuntu Wiki)